# How can I use Phing to SCP directory with symlinks inside it?

Tags: php, symlink, scp, phing

I'm just playing around with Phing, and I've setup a task like this:

```
<scp .... >
    <fileset dir="/my/dir">
        <include name="**" />
    </fileset>
</scp>
```

But it fails when it gets to a symlink within my directory (the symlink is a relative symlink pointing at another directory inside `/my/dir structure`.

How can I have Phing transfer these symbolic links? Or should I use another method?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the expected behaviour is. Whether you want to transfer the actual symbolic link or the dereferenced file. However this might not be a problem of the actual scp task but rather of the fileset.

Have a look at http://phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixD-CoreTypes.html#Fileset and try playing around with the expandsymboliclinks flag.

Comment: I want to transfer the actual symbolic link so the remote server receives the symbolic link. I've since started using an rsync task to sync files, which is more efficient for me anyways.